# Pasar de Java a Python

Tags: python

Una pregunta rápida, esta pequeña instrucción de Java como iría en python?

```
int[][] move = new int[3][2];
```

Comment: Te sugerimos nuevamente revisar [ask] para crear preguntas en el sitio. El titulo es importante https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359553/de-java-a-python

Answer (score 1):

En la pasada aportación te lo he dejado en el código. De todas formas te lo escribo otra vez:

```
move = [[0 for x in range(4)] for y in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que necesitas para crear un array especificando sus dimensiones serían las siguientes líneas:

```
import numpy as np
inmove = np.array((3,2))
```

Las mismas dan este resultado el siguiente resultado:

```
Out[5]: array([3, 2])
```